# Deciphering handwritten kanji

Tags: kanji, handwriting

I've gotten in the habit of transcribing/translating Japanese fanart for my friends. I do well with typed characters, but this artist's handwriting has me stumped:

[image]

Here is my loose transcription, with ... replacing the unknown characters and () around characters I'm very unsure of:

(せ)っかく...ったお...立ち(そ)...さっておりますのに，そのように...されてはもったいないです！

I'll also admit I thought the っs were commas at first, because they're so small. They might still be. I have no idea.

Comment: If you train yourself to handwrite Kanji sentences too, you will naturally learn how to decrypt Kanji handwriting.

Comment: @immateur, could you please rewrite your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

It's "せっかく整ったお顔立ちをなさっておりますのに、そのように隠されてはもったいないです！".